# Create a factor based on POSIXlt time?

Tags: r, split, dataframe, cut, posixct

I am currently dealing with data stored in data frame with time in one column. I have to split whole day to some periods. Up to now, I have been doing this based on full hours

```
workingdata <- read.csv(filename)
workingdata$dateI <- as.POSIXlt(workingdata$dateI,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
workingdata$hourI <- workingdata$dateI$hour
workingdata$shift <- cut(workingdata$hourI, breaks=c(0,6,13,23),
                         labels=c("morning","midday","evening"),
                         include.lowest=TRUE,right=TRUE)
```

This worked fine, and created factor with three levels - `morning` for hours from 0:00 to 6:59, `midday` from 7:00 to 13:59, and `evening` from 14:00 to 23:59.

Now I would like to do similar thing, but with cuts based on minutes/seconds, e.g. `midday` starting at `11:34:12`. Is there a way to do it with cuts based purely on POSIXlt? What will be the best approach?

**Edit:** I have tried specifying the cut as a POSIXlt object, but it seems to be including the date always, so it is not what I want...

```
> brk<-as.POSIXlt("11:34:12",format="%H:%M:%S")
> brk
[1] "2012-11-16 11:34:12"
```

Comment: did you try indicating the breaks in the format you require?  If so, what happened there.

Comment: As far as I have understood, POSIXlt requires me to specify the full date, including day. I have added this to the main question.

Comment: what happens if you splice out the times from brk? `justTime <- strsplit(as.character(brk), " ")[[c(1,2)]]`

Comment: if that doesnt work, perhaps post some sample data?

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the differences between your data and the beginning of the day your data come from and compare them to your cutoff point.

```
foo <- as.POSIXlt(runif(100,min=0,max=1000009),origin="2012-01-01")
bar <- rep(NA,length(foo))
morning <- 
    foo-as.POSIXlt(paste(1900+foo$year,"-",1+foo$mon,"-",foo$mday,sep=""))<
    11*60+34+12/60
bar[morning] <- "morning"
```

The midday and evening shifts and turning `bar` into a factor are left as exercises for the reader ;-)